# Retrieve height/width of bootstrap 4 popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to retrieve the `height/width` of the Bootstrap popover dynamically.
I have the context which I try grab the `height/width`:

```
console.log(context);
console.log(context.getBoundingClientRect().height);
console.log(context.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

This outputs the Bootstrap element:

```
<div class="popover fade bs-tether-element bs-tether-enabled bs-tether
element-attached-middle bs-tether-element-attached-left bs-tether-target
attached-middle bs-tether-target-attached-right in" role="tooltip"
id="popover537457" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; transform:
translateX(904px) translateY(227px) translateZ(0px);"><h3 class="popover
title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><div class="tooltip-content">To learn
more about naming convention please <a href="#">click here</a></div></div
</div>
```

The `height/width` however that I `console log` out above **return 0**.
Anyone know how I can accomplish retrieving the `height/width` of a Bootstrap 4 popover?

Comment: Add your html, css and javascript in jsfiddle...it will be better to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popover fade bs-tether-element bs-tether-enabled bs-tether
element-attached-middle bs-tether-element-attached-left bs-tether-target
attached-middle bs-tether-target-attached-right in" role="tooltip"
id="popover537457" style="display: block"><h3 class="popover
title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><div class="tooltip-content">To learn
more about naming convention please <a href="#">click here</a></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You'll get values like "276px" for the width and "98px" for the height. Those are what I got on this page : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#example-using-the-container-option with the Live Demo. Check the values in the console with the width and height values on the Computed-tab of Dev Tools. :

```
window.getComputedStyle(context).getPropertyValue("width");
window.getComputedStyle(context).getPropertyValue("height");
```

// For numeric values without "px" postpended, wrap in parseInt() :

```
parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(context).getPropertyValue("width"));
parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(context).getPropertyValue("height");
```

// OR If you could determine the ID(s) of all your popovers on that page in an array you could do the following (replace the popover ID string literal with a variable or array element containing the ID of the popover.) :

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('popover537457')).getPropertyValue("width")
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('popover537457')).getPropertyValue("height")
```

I tested in Chrome's console with the 2 lines above (and a different popover ID of course).